# Best Db Design for parent-child table and derived foregin key On delete Cascade

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys

On the following I get an error from SQL server that it is not possible to lay a foreign key ON DELETE:

**TABLE1: function**

- PK: Id
- Name
- Category
- FK: To_Same_Table_Id NULLABLE ("a function can have a child function")

**TABLE2: attributes**

- PK_Id
- FK_To_TAble 1 On Delete Cascade (non nullable since it is always derived from Table 1) (a function has multiple attributes) (and if a function gets deleted then also its attributes should be deleted)

SQL Server refuses to put the FK in since it complains it could cause circulare relationships.  Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_TABLE2_Table1Id' on table 'TABLe2' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I think that the reason for this is that if Table 1 "1" gets deleted that then table 2 "1,2,3" get deleted but because if Table 1 record 1 has a reference to "2" it will also deleted "2", if "2" would have a reference from also a specific Table 2 then it would be circular.

So I understand the problem but ... im looking for the answer.

Comment: Can you share the actual DDL of your tables instead of an overview?

Comment: Don't do cascading deletes. Problem solved.